# SEDE query to find out how many posts have been protected with spam on them

Tags: support, data-explorer

We are in the middle of an important discussion on our site about how we use the protection tool and we need some data for that discussion.

Specifically, how many posts have ever been protected on the site after having had one or more answers deleted for being spam?

It would also be helpful if the query could include the date that the questions were unprotected.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't use SEDE to tell you that.

Comment: @rene Dang, I assume the spam deletion part is the problematic aspect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While rene is right in that we can't figure out from SEDE which posts have been deleted as spam, we *do* know which ones have spam flags. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/1261656/protected-questions-with-spam-flagged-answers) lists eight questions which are protected (at least last Sunday) and have spam flags on answers:

- [3.5e Variant Rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9270)
- [What Wizard schools are best to specialize in? Which schools are best to sacrifice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19557)
- [Software for adding atmosphere via music and sounds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23201)
- [Handy spells to have on scrolls for a specific scenario?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/29596)
- [Storytelling with lie detection](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34366)
- [How does wizard & cleric spell preparation and casting work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44400)
- [How can I heal undead creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53556)
- [What should I do about a religious player who refuses to accept the existence of multiple gods in D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148911)

A similar query for questions that were protected (but aren't right now) is [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/1261658/formerly-but-not-currently-protected-questions-with-spam-flagged-answers). Note that it doesn't assume anything about when the answer was posted (before or after the protection).

Comment: oh! any way to tweak this to find questions that are not currently protected but that have been at any time in the past?

Answer (score 5):

You can't have an exact SEDE query but [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/1261622) gets close.

I'm looking here for questions that are protected (event 19) and don't have an more recent unprotect (event 20). Then I join with `postswithdeleted` to find if the question has deleted answers. I can't tell from SEDE why that answer got deleted. You would need to hand-check the 62 results on RPG.

```
select distinct p.id as [Post Link]
from posts p
inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
inner join postswithdeleted pwd on pwd.parentid = p.id
where posthistorytypeid = 19
and not exists 
  (select 1 
   from posthistory phun 
   where phun.postid = p.id
   and phun.posthistorytypeid = 20
   and phun.creationdate > ph.creationdate)
and p.posttypeid = 1 
and pwd.deletiondate is not null 
and pwd.posttypeid = 2
and pwd.score < 0
```

If you're interested in questions that were once protected you can remove the `not exists` clause.
If you consider that an answer that is spam flagged also gets a down vote, you might further restrict the resultset by adding pwd.score < 0 so that only questions with a negatively scored deleted answer are considered.

Comment: So, the issue we might have here if I understand correctly is that currently on the site I'm looking at, all the questions are unprotected. Any way to remove the qualification that the question must still be protected from the query? Would just removing `and phun.posthistorytypeid = 20` do the trick?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I hand checked the first result: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/267/timeline that one seem protected to me?